# Is (Convolution + PixelShuffle) the same as SubPixel convolution?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working on the ArXiV paper [Is the deconvolution layer the same as a convolutional layer?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.07009.pdf). The topic is to upsample, by an upscale factor `r`, a tensor `x` from shape `(N, C, H, W)` to shape `(N, C, H*r, W*r)`.

In that paper they introduce an equivalence between the two following methods (the point being the second one should be more computationally efficient than the first one):

- **SubPixel method**: create sub pixel image, then convolution in sub pixel space with a kernel of shape `(C, C, Hk * r, Wk * r)`
- **PixelShuffle method**: convolution with kernel `(C * r * r, C, Hk, Wk)`, then periodic shuffling

Those methods are pictured by the Figure 6 and 7 of the paper, that I reproduced and animated below to highlight my interrogations about the equivalence statement. After the figures comes a `pytorch` implementation to support those interrogations.

#### Questions

Am I missing something or the following is true?:

1. SubPixel output size:

   - SubPixel method gives an output image of size `(6, 6)` and not `(8, 8)` as represented in the figure.
   - SubPixel method can give an output image of size `(8, 8)` by adding more padding in the subpixel space, but then last row and last column of the output image are full of zeros.
2. Except for "purple" pixels, there is a spatial shift of values between both output images:

   - Purple pixels are aligned
   - Blue pixels are shifted on dim W
   - Green pixels are shifted on dim H
   - Red pixels are shifted on dim H and dim W
   - e.g. :

     - PixShuff: Output blue pixel `(0, 1)` is computed from input pixels `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]`
     - SubPix: Output blue pixel `(0, 1)` is computed from input pixels `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)]`. In PixShuff, those input pixels are used to compute the output blue pixel `(0, 3)`.

#### Figures

##### SubPixel method

[image: SubPixel (Figure 6)]

##### PixelShuffle method

[image: PixelShuffle (Figure 7)]

#### Implementation

Notes:

- I added some assertions to make sure I understand the dimensions correctly.
- There is still some hard-coded values for padding etc.

The main script:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

torch.set_printoptions(precision=2)
torch.manual_seed(34)


def main():
    N, Cin, H, W = 1, 1, 4, 4
    Cout = Cin
    ratio = 2
    Hk, Wk = 2, 2

    x = torch.rand(N, Cin, H, W)
    x_padded = torch.zeros(N, Cin, H + 1, W + 1)
    x_padded[..., :-1, :-1] = x

    kernel_stacked = torch.rand(Cout * ratio * ratio, Cin, Hk, Wk)
    kernel_shuffled = F.pixel_shuffle(kernel_stacked.movedim(0, 1), ratio)

    x_up_pixshuff = upsample_conv_pixshuff(x_padded, ratio, kernel_stacked)
    x_up_subpix = upsample_subpix_conv(x, ratio, kernel_shuffled)
    x_up_subpix_padded = upsample_subpix_conv(x_padded, ratio, kernel_shuffled)

    purple_subpix = x_up_subpix_padded[..., ::2, ::2]
    purple_pixshuff = x_up_pixshuff[..., ::2, ::2]
    blue_subpix = x_up_subpix_padded[..., ::2, 1::2]
    blue_pixshuff = x_up_pixshuff[..., ::2, 1::2]
    green_subpix = x_up_subpix_padded[..., 1::2, ::2]
    green_pixshuff = x_up_pixshuff[..., 1::2, ::2]
    red_subpix = x_up_subpix_padded[..., 1::2, 1::2]
    red_pixshuff = x_up_pixshuff[..., 1::2, 1::2]

    # ... Long list of print statements given below


def upsample_conv_pixshuff(x, upscale_factor, kernel):
    N, Cin, H, W = x.shape
    Cout_r_r, _, H, W = kernel.shape
    assert kernel.shape[1] == Cin
    assert Cout_r_r == Cin * upscale_factor * upscale_factor

    x_up_stacked = F.conv2d(x, kernel)
    return F.pixel_shuffle(x_up_stacked, upscale_factor)


def upsample_subpix_conv(x, upscale_factor, kernel):
    N, Cin, Hin, Win = x.shape
    Cout, _, Hk, Wk = kernel.shape
    assert kernel.shape[1] == Cin
    assert Cout == Cin
    Hout, Wout = Hin * upscale_factor, Win * upscale_factor

    x_interleaved = torch.zeros(N, Cout, Hout + 1, Wout + 1)
    x_interleaved[..., :-1:upscale_factor, :-1:upscale_factor] = x
    return F.conv2d(x_interleaved, kernel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output given by the long list of print statements:

```
-> SubPixel method gives an output image of size `(6, 6)` and not (8, 8)

x_up_pixshuff.shape = torch.Size([1, 1, 8, 8])
x_up_subpix.shape   = torch.Size([1, 1, 6, 6])

-> SubPixel method can give an output image of size `(8, 8)`
by adding more padding in the subpixel space,
but then ouptput last row/col image are full of zeros

x_up_subpix_padded.shape = torch.Size([1, 1, 8, 8])
torch.all(x_up_subpix_padded[..., :, -1] == 0) = tensor(True)
torch.all(x_up_subpix_padded[..., -1, 0] == 0) = tensor(True)

-> There is a spatial shift between output images
    - Purple pixels are aligned
torch.all(purple_subpix == purple_pixshuff) = tensor(True)
    - Blue pixels are shifted on dim W
torch.all(blue_subpix[..., :-1] == blue_pixshuff[..., 1:]) = tensor(True)
    - Green pixels are shifted on dim H
torch.all(green_subpix[..., :-1, :] == green_pixshuff[..., 1:, :]) = tensor(True)
    - Red pixels are shifted on dim H and dim W
torch.all(red_subpix[..., :-1, :-1] == red_pixshuff[..., 1:, 1:]) = tensor(True)
```

The complete matrices:

```
x_up_pixshuff
tensor([[[[0.73, 0.43, 0.26, 0.33, 0.74, 0.64, 0.36, 0.17],
          [1.17, 1.29, 0.17, 0.82, 0.61, 1.24, 0.79, 0.69],
          [0.88, 0.62, 0.41, 0.21, 0.56, 0.50, 0.56, 0.28],
          [1.15, 1.35, 1.07, 0.87, 0.89, 1.36, 1.12, 1.03],
          [0.92, 0.90, 1.21, 0.93, 0.94, 0.78, 0.64, 0.37],
          [0.84, 1.94, 1.67, 2.35, 1.32, 2.08, 0.96, 1.03],
          [0.36, 0.44, 0.78, 0.71, 0.63, 0.55, 0.34, 0.23],
          [0.23, 1.09, 0.61, 1.57, 0.51, 1.20, 0.30, 0.45]]]])

x_up_subpix
tensor([[[[0.73, 0.33, 0.26, 0.64, 0.74, 0.17],
          [1.15, 0.87, 1.07, 1.36, 0.89, 1.03],
          [0.88, 0.21, 0.41, 0.50, 0.56, 0.28],
          [0.84, 2.35, 1.67, 2.08, 1.32, 1.03],
          [0.92, 0.93, 1.21, 0.78, 0.94, 0.37],
          [0.23, 1.57, 0.61, 1.20, 0.51, 0.45]]]])

x_up_subpix_padded
tensor([[[[0.73, 0.33, 0.26, 0.64, 0.74, 0.17, 0.36, 0.00],
          [1.15, 0.87, 1.07, 1.36, 0.89, 1.03, 1.12, 0.00],
          [0.88, 0.21, 0.41, 0.50, 0.56, 0.28, 0.56, 0.00],
          [0.84, 2.35, 1.67, 2.08, 1.32, 1.03, 0.96, 0.00],
          [0.92, 0.93, 1.21, 0.78, 0.94, 0.37, 0.64, 0.00],
          [0.23, 1.57, 0.61, 1.20, 0.51, 0.45, 0.30, 0.00],
          [0.36, 0.71, 0.78, 0.55, 0.63, 0.23, 0.34, 0.00],
          [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]]]])
```

The list of print statements for reference:

```py
print("-> SubPixel method gives an output image of size `(6, 6)` and not (8, 8)\n")
    print(f"{x_up_pixshuff.shape = }")
    print(f"{x_up_subpix.shape   = }")

    print(
        "\n-> SubPixel method can give an output image of size `(8, 8)`"
        "\nby adding more padding in the subpixel space,"
        "\nbut then ouptput last row/col image are full of zeros\n"
    )
    print(f"{x_up_subpix_padded.shape = }")
    print(f"{torch.all(x_up_subpix_padded[..., :, -1] == 0) = }")
    print(f"{torch.all(x_up_subpix_padded[..., -1, 0] == 0) = }")

    print("\n-> There is a spatial shift between output images")
    print("    - Purple pixels are aligned")
    print(f"{torch.all(purple_subpix == purple_pixshuff) = }")
    print("    - Blue pixels are shifted on dim W")
    print(f"{torch.all(blue_subpix[..., :-1] == blue_pixshuff[..., 1:]) = }")
    print("    - Green pixels are shifted on dim H")
    print(f"{torch.all(green_subpix[..., :-1, :] == green_pixshuff[..., 1:, :]) = }")
    print("    - Red pixels are shifted on dim H and dim W")
    print(f"{torch.all(red_subpix[..., :-1, :-1] == red_pixshuff[..., 1:, 1:]) = }")

    print("\n-> For reference, the complete matrices:")
    print("\nx_up_pixshuff")
    print(x_up_pixshuff)
    print("\nx_up_subpix")
    print(x_up_subpix)
    print("\nx_up_subpix_padded")
    print(x_up_subpix_padded)
```